# MySQL - разделение полей на отдельные таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Привет всем!

Появилась задача - оптимизировать структуру БД MySQL, выделив некоторые поля в отдельные таблицы.

БД содержит данные о товарах, их категориях и нескольких полей доп. свойств.

Все содержится в одной огромной таблице из полей VARCHAR(в основном).

Нужно найти уникальные строки VARCHAR для разных полей и выделить их в отдельную таблицы, оставив в главной только ключ.

Возможно ли такое провернуть, использую только MySQL?

Если нет, то подскажите хотя бы общий алгоритм - очень боюсь сам испортить данные в этой БД.

**1. - Структура существующей БД - только нужные в данной случае поля.**

**ГЛАВНАЯ ТАБЛИЦА**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (уникальный ИД позиции товара)
`prod_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL - название позиции(неуникальное)
`prod_cat` varchar(64) NOT NULL - название категории(неуникальное)
`prod_prop01` varchar(64) NOT NULL - название свойства1(неуникальное)
`prod_prop02` varchar(64) NOT NULL - название свойства2(неуникальное)
```

**2. - Хотелось бы получить след. структуру**

**ГЛАВНАЯ ТАБЛИЦА**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (уникальный ИД позиции товара)
`prod_name` int(10) - ИД названия позиции(уникальный)
`prod_cat` int(10) - ИД категории(уникальный)
`prod_prop01` int(10) - ИД свойства1(уникальный)
`prod_prop02` int(10) - ИД свойства2(уникальный)
```

**ТАБЛИЦА НАЗВАНИЙ**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (уникальный ИД Названия)
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL - название позиции(уникальное!)
```

И такие же таблицы для - категории, свойства1 и свойства2.

Уверен, что задача довольно таки банальная - декомпозиция БД.

Но я не спец. пока еще и не успел дочитать главы об этом и имею достаточно поверхностное представление о методах декомпозиции.

Буду рад любым дельным советам. Спасибо.

Comment: В теории реляционных БД это называется нормализацией, а то, что Вы хотите получить - вторая нормальная форма

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм достаточно прост: каждая таблица для хранения отдельных сущностей. В вашем случае такими сущностями являются:

- prod_cat - категории
- prod_name - товары
- prod_prop - свойства

В одной категории может быть несколько товаров, у одного товара - несколько свойств. Данные связываются по ключам, для этого в каждой таблице создается первичный ключ, а в дочерних (таблицы товаров и свойств) еще и внешний ключ:

Таблица категорий:

```
id       int,
prod_cat text
```

Таблица товаров:

```
id        int,
id_cat    int,
prod_name text
```

Таблица свойств:

```
id        int,
id_prod   int,
prod_prop text
```

Свойство1 и свойство2, если отталкиваться от вашего вопроса, одна сущность. Однако в случае, если речь идет, к примеру о сроке годности и штрих-коде, то тогда имеет смысл эти данные оставить в таблице товаров:

```
id          int,
id_cat      int,
prod_name   text,
best_before date,
bar_code    text
```

Провернуть это, используя чисто MySQL, можно. Создаете нужные вам таблицы, копируете исходную таблицу (на всякий случай) и создаете в ней несколько полей для первичных ключей из оптимизированных таблиц, а потом копируете в оптимизированные таблицы нужные вам данные. (*Принцип такой: перенесли данные из исходной таблицы, в вашей новой таблице при этом сгенерировались данные в поле id (автоинкремент), эти id вы копируете в исходную таблицу. Повторяете, пока все данные не раскидаются по нужным таблицам.*)

Обратите внимание на такие запросы:

- SELECT DISTINCT... - уберет дубли из выборки,
- GROUP BY... - тоже мощное средство для объединения одинаковых данных,
- INSERT INTO... SELECT... - копия данных из таблицы в таблицу.

За данные не переживайте: при таком переносе вы их не потеряете, потому как весь процесс - копирование из таблиц в таблицы. Однако, бэкап никогда не помешает.

Answer (score 0):

Немного не согласен с предыдущим ответом, была похожая задача так же разнести базу на структурно -вложенную, но как оказалось, что все текстовые значения в первоначально таблице вбивались вручную и кто как писал - орфографические ошибки, пробелы и тому подобная требуха. Вышли из положения следующим образом - сформировали справочник через GROUP BY по колонке, вручную выкрыжили двойники (пришлось в некоторых случаях сломать мозг) ну а потом по предложенному алгоритму. К сожалению система для которой это делалось прожила всего год после нашей обработки (которая заняла 1 день подготовка и 2 недели ручная правка справочников) из-за кризиса 2009 года, клиент разорился, и поэтому трудов немного жаль :)

Comment: В моем случае все не так грустно, данные вбивались полу-автоматическим путем из других систем. Поэтому все названия и строки свойств без ошибок.